# DisableFormatting for a single instance of Grid, but format expressions inside that Grid

Tags: output-formatting, hold

I have an expression like:

```
Grid[{{
    HoldForm[
      ...
      Grid[...]
      ...
    ]
  },{
    ...
    Grid[...]
    ...        
  }}]
```

This almost gives what I want, but the `Grid` inside `HoldForm` is formatting. I want everything inside the `HoldForm` to appear just like when you [enter two-dimensional input](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EnteringInputInNotebooks.html).

My goal is to produce an image with the two-dimensional input above the output that expression produces. I can't take a screenshot because the output is animated, and I want to export everything as a GIF.

I put `DisableFormatting` around the desired Grid, but that disabled formatting for everything inside the `Grid` also (it displayed all the expressions inside the grid in `InputForm` not `StandardForm`). I want `HoldForm` and formatting to apply inside that `Grid`, but I don't want that grid itself to format.

Comment: Inactivate may be what you want, but I'm not clear on how you want this to look. Do you want to see the head Grid or not? I get that you want to sort of display the "input" above the "output", but I'm just not grokking what HoldForm inside and the Grid not formatting actually means.

Comment: Can you provide a simple example/picture of what you mean?

Comment: Perhaps you can just wrap the head Grid in HoldForm only, e.g., `HoldForm[Grid][...]`?

Comment: @lericr I do want `Grid` to show in the output (because that's part of the input, but `HoldForm` is not part of the input, so it's good that doesn't show). `Inactivate` is very much like what I want (just for that instance), but the help files showed that inactive functions/symbols appeared in a different color (which I don't want) and I couldn't figure out how to use `Inactivate` when I tested a small example.

Comment: @CarlWoll That does exactly what I want! I didn't realize I could just put something weird like that in front of the square brackets (I don't fully understand how Mathematica treats square brackets specially - different than parentheses). Can you put that in an answer so I can accept it?